# Selenium C# - Loading a profile throws exception in Firefox 48

Tags: c#, selenium, firefox

I am using gecko/marionette driver and have tried both selenium 2 and selenium 3.

I've successfully started a Firefox session with the web driver and without a profile using both options and services to specify a binary:

```
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.BrowserExecutableLocation = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla\Firefox\firefox.exe";
driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

or

```
FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";
driver = new FirefoxDriver(service);
```

However, when I try to load a profile into it by adding options:

```
 options.Profile = profile;
```

it gives a `corrupt deflate stream` exceptionn.

This also occurs when I manually specify the binary file and then try to load the profile (which is deprecated in version 3)

This same profile grab and loading was working prior to the new Firefox update. Is there anything special that needs to be done to get this working?

Comment: where you able to resolve or find a workaround for this? Am facing exactly the same issue. Am on Selenium 3 (beta) and Firefox 48.0.2

Comment: @KarthikBalasubramanian I have not been able to resolve this, no.

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered the same problem `corrupt deflate stream` when loading custom profile, and here is what helped me:

I opened the folder of my custom profile `%AppData%\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\TestProfile` and deleted all empty (0 kB size) files. (they were "AlternateServices.txt" and "parent.lock" in the root of profile directory)

After that the following code worked like a charm:

```
        var FirefoxProfileManager = new FirefoxProfileManager();
        var profile = FirefoxProfileManager.GetProfile("TestProfile");
        //driver = new FirefoxDriver(profile);
        var firefoxService = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
        var options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.Profile = profile;
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxService, options, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30));
```

Comment: Saved my day! Thank you!

Comment: worked for me. Specifically I deleted "AlternateServices.txt" and "parent.lock" which had zero kb size. They were in the root of my targeted profile folder

Answer (score 0):

The below works for me when using the default profile, I have used this to solve an issue where-by its not using a root cert that we need to get through our security system:

```
FirefoxDriverService service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\\TestData\Dependencies", "geckodriver.exe");
        service.FirefoxBinaryPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe";
        FirefoxProfileManager profileM = new FirefoxProfileManager();
        FirefoxProfile profile = profileM.GetProfile("default");


        //service.Port = 64444;
        FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
        options.Profile = profile;

        Instance = new FirefoxDriver(service,options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
        TurnOnWait();
```

HTH

Comment: This still causes a `corrupt deflate stream` error for me using Selenium 3.0 and Geckodriver 0.14